# How to plot query result on Overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am using overpass turbo web http://overpass-turbo.eu/#

after typing in

```
[out:csv(::lat,::lon;false)];
relation(2081626);>;out;
```

I get already a list of coordinates, under "data" tab

```
48.0786156  11.5510212
48.0769149  11.5502003
48.0763526  11.5505930
48.0768127  11.5502292
48.0761811  11.5499233
...
```

How could I plot this list of coordinates on "Map" tab as a route, on the map

Answer (score 1):

try this Overpass XML

```
<osm-script>
  <id-query ref="2081626" type="relation"/>
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```